# RSAT-AD-Tools-Feature enabled but AD-module not available

Tags: windows-server-2019

On our Window Server 2019 Datacenter system I enabled the RSAT-AD-Tools-Feature but the module is not available. Also `Get-Module -ListAvailable` doesn't list it.

[image]

Any idea anyone what the issue is here?

Comment: Within *Expand AD DS and AD LDS Tools+ in the optional Windows features, have you enabled, Active Directory Module for Windows Powershell?  You will want to verify that it’s enabled by using the Roles and Features Wizard.  If you run *import-module activedirectory* then run the company do you get the same error?  Asking you to use the wizard has a specific purpose.  Asking you to first import the module the run the command serves another purpose

Comment: Thank you. I can't find it in the gui but command line installation worked.

Answer (score 0):

As Ramhound hinted it needed to be installed separately:

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online  | 
  ? featurename -match 'ActiveDirectory-Power' |
  Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online
```

As mentioned in my above comment, I could not find it in the gui (not even any RSAT feature). Apparently what is listed with `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature` is something that has a *parent* feature which needs to be installed first.

Most of know it of course already but I don't want to leave it unmentioned: Windows sucks!